# Kubernetes host ingress with nested subdomains (GCP)

Tags: dns, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, devops, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to setup a K8s deployment where ingress's controllers can define a service as a subdomain. i.e. `app1` can define itself to get traffic from `app1.sub.domain.io` in its ingress config.

I have a DNS A Record `*.sub.domain.io` that points to a `Load Balancer`. That load balancer is pointing to the cluster's instance group.

So if I am right all traffic that goes to anything at sub.domain.io will land inside the cluster and just need to route said traffic.

Below are the k8 configs, which has a pod, a service and an ingress. The pods are healthy and working, I believe the service isn't required but will want other pods to talk to it via internal DNS so it's added.

The ingress rules have a host `app1.sub.domain.io`, so in theory, curl'ing app1.sub.domain.io should follow:
DNS -> Load Balancer -> Cluster -> Ingress Controller -> Pod

At the moment when I try to hit `app1.sub.domain.io` it just hangs. I have tried not having service, making external-name service and doesn't work.

I don't want to go down the route of using the loadBalancer ingress as that makes a new external IP that needs to be applied to DNS records manually, or with a nasty bash script that waits for services external IP and runs GCP command, and we don't want to do this for each service.

Ref links:https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting

**Deployment**

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: app1
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: app1
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: xxxx:latest
        name: app1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
          - name: NODE_ENV
            value: production
```

**Service**

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: app1
  labels:
    app: app1
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: app1
  type: ClusterIP
```

**Ingress**

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app1-ingress
  labels:
    app: app1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app1.sub.domain.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: app1
          servicePort: 80
```

Once everything is deployed if you query 
`kubectl get pods,services,ingresses -l app=app1`

```
NAME                       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
po/app1-6d4b9d8c5-4gcz5    1/1       Running   0          20m
po/app1-6d4b9d8c5-m4kwq    1/1       Running   0          20m
po/app1-6d4b9d8c5-rpm9l    1/1       Running   0          20m

NAME        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
svc/app1    ClusterIP   x.x.x.x         <none>        80/TCP    20m

NAME                HOSTS                   ADDRESS   PORTS     AGE
ing/app1-ingress    app1.sub.domain.io                80        20m
```

**----------------------------------- Update -----------------------------------**

Currently doing this, not ideal. Have global static IP that's assigned to a DNS record.

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: app1
  labels:
    app: app1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: app1
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app1-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: app1-static-ip
  labels:
    app: app1-static-ip
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: app1
    servicePort: 80
```

Comment: I think that the workaround in your edit *is* the solution. What would you like to improve?

Comment: Did you get to resolve this? We wanted to setup a staging domain at `app.stg.xxx.com`. We use `app-stg.xxx.com` as a workaround until we have more info on this.

Answer (score 0):

*.sub.domain.io should point to the IP of the Ingress.

You can use a static IP for the Ingress by following the instructions in the tutorial here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer#step_5_optional_configuring_a_static_ip_address

Comment: The ingress isn't external, as I said I "could" do that way but then I need update DNS records each time which is defeating the point. If I add another service this will break too. As i wouldn't be able to make dynamic route in DNS `*.sub.domain.io`, it would have to be `app1.sub.domain.io` -> Ip of Ingress which sucks.

Comment: why can you not make a `*.sub.domain.io` wildcard A record? ...works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding path to your Ingress:

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app1-ingress
  labels:
    app: app1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app1.sub.domain.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: app1
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

If that doesn't work, please post the output of describe service and describe ingress.

Do you have an Ingress Controller?
Traffic should go LB-> Ingress Controller-> Ingress-> Service ClusterIP-> Pods